# how to hide tabbar when I use NavController to push view?

Tags: ios, ios6, ios5.1

I have tried two kinds of methods below:

---

> 1.[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];

---

> 2.
>   self.navigationController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
>
> [self.navigationController pushViewController:OneViewController animated:YES];

But the result is that the tabbar items is hidden, but there is still a black block there, 
[image]

I guess it is because the view's tab bar style is not set to None.Just like the IB's view setting below:
[image]

How to solve this problem, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide the nav bar use this code

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

To show the nav bar you can use this code

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

And here is the doc's that might be helpful my friend

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope that helps you man.

EDIT

Here is a github project for hiding the tab bar. Hope this helps you.

https://github.com/idevsoftware/Cocoa-Touch-Additions/tree/master/UITabBarController_setHidden

Let me know if this is what ou are looking for and if you need more help man.

Comment: thanks, but I dont mean the NavigationBar hidden. How to hide tab bar?